# What probability topics can be read without Measure Theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question, brownian-motion, ergodic-theory

I know Intermediate Probability Theory and Statistics (distributions, convergence concepts, characteristic functions, etc.) and am pretty good at these. I would love to know more about Probability Theory. Unfortunately, although I am aware that Measure Theory is an integral tool for advanced Probability Theory, I have not taken a full course of Measure Theory. However, I intend to study Measure Theory as soon as possible.

I am listing some topics in Probability Theory that seem interesting to me. I would be obliged if you could tell me whether I can start (at least) on these topics **without Measure Theoretic knowledge**. I would be grateful if you can inform me which topics exactly I can do without Measure theory.

1. Branching Processes
2. Ergodic Theory
3. Martingales
4. Percolation Theory
5. Random Graphs
6. Random Walks on Graphs
7. Non-Commutative Probability
8. Theory of Extremes and Point Processes
9. Theory of Large Deviations
10. Extreme Value Theory
11. Brownian Motion
12. Diffusions

Thank you for your time!! It would be a great confidence booster to know that I can start studying some of these subjects without Measure Theoretic knowledge. I am in any way going to learn Measure Theoretic Probability within a few months.

Comment: This is a toughy. Once you transcend the realm of simple coin and dice tossing, probability is *defined* only in terms of measures.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Actually I was thinking if it would be possible for me to obtain introductory knowledge about these topics initially, without delving into the details and hence without using measure theory. Would you suggest that I learn Markov Chains and related Stochastic Processes instead?

Comment: 5 and 6 seem to me like themes that don't require a knowledge of measure theory. At least not at an elementary level. Ergodic theory is a definite no. Ergodic theory is essentially a topic in measure theory as much as it is one in probability theory. Technically, 7 is also not requiring measure theory. But it does require what could be called the non-commutative version of it, which is von Neumann algebras. Which is more advanced than measure theory.

Comment: This gets more and more interesting!!

Answer (score 3):

To a large extent, it depends on whether you are interested
in learning important properties and facts or whether you
want to do proofs and eventually original research, whether
you are interested primarily in theory or in applications.

Many of the properties and much of what is done in applications
is accessible without measure theory and many important
applications are done (sometimes beyond what is known
for sure theoretically) by simulation.

For example, while it is true that ergodic theory is mainly
a topic in measure theory, a lot of the applications of
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) assume ergodicity without
theoretical backing. (On a case by case basis, numerical and graphical methods are
used to verify apparent convergence over the long run, and
one hopes for the best.) Of course, this is an open area
of research, and theoretical results will almost surely
be based on measure theory.

Many concrete applications of Brownian Motion are done 
by simulation, and some principles can be demonstrated
by simulation. Some of the more intricate properties
cannot even be properly understood without measure theory.

Maybe you are asking if you can meaningfully explore any
of these topics without measure theory, in order to confirm whether
you are really interested in them. To a large extent,
the answer is yes for most of these topics.

The rest of the answer is that you should learn measure
theory as soon as possible, because this list alone is
a good indication you would find the topic worthwhile.
Why not get started on measure theory ASAP, concurrently
explore what you can from your list. Each endeavor will reinforce the
other.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!! Actually I am an aspiring probabilist : I am inclined towards original research. I am going to start studying Measure Theoretic Probability under the guidance of a Professor (as an extra course). If I start with Ash, or Durrett, (because I find Billingsley too terse, and I found Durrett and Ash contain many of the topics I listed in my question), would I be able to cope up, according to you? Thank you once again.

Comment: These days, a lot of original research in probability and related fields is suggested by applications. Many of the applications in the topics you mention can be understood without measure theory. While your're learning measure theory, maybe build your intuition by looking at applications and trying some simulation. I think intuition is crucial to useful original research (the kind of articles that get read, not just published in Proceedings of the NE BlahBlah Consortium for Advancement of Whatsis and never read.)

Comment: So would you suggest that alongside reading theory, I request my Professors to help me understand how things can be simulated? This is not something that hasn't crossed my mind. I am actually in Second Year of an undergraduate Statistics course, and I do know some programming in R. However, since most of the things require Bootstrapping and Bayesian methods I have been told to wait until they are covered in class. I would love to see some applications of these. Which journals would you suggest for reading? I would not usually prefer too technical journals right now.

Comment: I am a big fan of probability simulation--even to the extent of coauthoring a book on it with former student/current colleague Suess, But I hesitate to encourage more than occasional distractions from your coursework, and do not want to contradict advisers who know you. Simple to moderately hard simulations are birthday matches (w/o eq. likely days), permutation tests, K-state Markov chains, random walks, M/M/1 queues (discretized time, or continuous time), crude discretized-time path with crossing probabilities of Brownian process. Maybe see Eudey's article in J Stat Ed on permutation tests.